# Text rendering in metal

Tags: metal

I am trying to develop my own mini game engine in Apple metal on a mac and I am stuck at a place where I want to render text on the GPU. I do not have much graphics programming experience and hence I am not sure how to do it. I stumbled upon an article written by warren more using signed distance fields. But I do not know how it works and I am unable to understand it completely (lack of my graphics knowledge) to implement it myself. The blog post has a code sample which is written in obj-c but unfortunately i do not know obj-c. Is there some swift version of it? Or can someone explain / give pointers on how to render text in metal?

Comment: You don't have to go all the way to using signed-distance fields at first; I'd recommend starting with the classic approach: one textured quad per glyph, using a pre-computed font atlas texture. There's a good tutorial series [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Text_Rendering_01). I know you said you don't know Objective-C, but you're going to need to learn how to read and translate from other languages and APIs if you want to succeed in your quest.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I will look into it. But as you said, I need to learn Obj-C to get more knowledge on this.

Answer (score 5):

I have been down this road before. I think you might find SceneKit useful if you are after 3D text.

If you are OK with using SceneKit to drive your rendering: [SCNText](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntext) with a `SCNView`.

If you have your own command buffer, and you can get away with blending your text on TOP of the rest of your graphics: you can still use `SCNText`, by using the `render()` method of a `SCNRenderer` to render to encode a scene's render commands onto a command buffer.

If you want to avoid SceneKit's rendering process, I would recommend doing this: create a SCNText in a SCNTransaction like so:

```
    import SceneKit
    SCNTransaction.begin()
    let sceneText = SCNText(string: text, extrusionDepth: extrusionDepth)
    SCNTransaction.commit()
    let mdlMesh = MDLMesh(scnGeometry: sceneText, bufferAllocator: yourBufferAllocator)
    let mesh = try MTKMesh(mesh: mdlMesh, device: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!)
```

This MTKMesh will have three vertex buffers; the first one (0) is a list of positions in `packed_float3` format, the second (1) a list of normals in `packed_float3` format, the third (2) a list of texture coordinates in `packed_float2` format. Just make sure to reflect that in your vertex shader. It will have 1-5 submeshes with their own index buffers, corresponding I believe to front, back, front chamfer, back chamfer, and extrusion side.

Now, if you are after 2D text, you can either use this method above with an extrusionDepth close to zero, or you can harness `CoreText` directly to do font metrics and render textured quads with a font atlas texture like the commenter suggested.

The ability to understand Objective-C is certainly useful as well, but you may not need it for this problem specifically. I tried to be brief on my explanations since I don't know what your exact goal is with this problem, but I can provide more detail on any of those methods upon request.

Comment: how about spritekit SKLabelNode for 2d?

Comment: Please elaborate on how to integrate CoreText with Metal.